# Explicitly define project source that can be accepted by intellij and maven for project setup

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project structured as below.

```
parent
   |---module1
       |----pom.xml
   |---module2
       |----pom.xml
   |---module3
       |----src\main\java\source1
       |----src\main\java\source2
       |----src\main\java\source3
       |----pom.xml
```

The issue here is intellij doesn't automatically recognize the sources under module3 and had to be defined explicitly under ***project setting > modules*** which is temporary and gets reset after every reimport.
Since intellij refers to standard `<sourceDirectory>` tag, I tried to put all sources under the tag but it accepts only single value.

Is there a way to configure the source folder under module3 on pom.xml so that maven and intellij both automatically recognizes the sources.

> maven version I am using is apache-maven-3.6.0 and intellij version is
> 2020.2

Comment: Why do you want three separate source directories in module3? It is far better to use standard maven layouts than try to configure something non-standard. You should probably also have a parent pom.xml in your top level directory, to provide your modules with dependencyManagement and default plugin configuration.

Comment: @tgdavies Actually its a legacy old project and over the time as gone very crucial. Changes to the structure will now cause a lot of issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.